# SQL Server required change password

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to block SQL Server forcing password change and sudden deactivation of old password? My application connects to the database and suddenly, after about 2/4 weeks, it loses connection with the database, and when I run SSMS and logging in, autherication: SQL Server Authentication requires set a new password.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/86903/5203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ALTER` the `LOGIN` to have `CHECK_EXPIRATION` set to `OFF`:

```sql
ALTER LOGIN YourLogin WITH CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF;
```

This is (at least for current versions) by default set to `OFF`, which likely means that the password is expiring by design though. If so I would suggest double checking before that *not* expiring the password is now intended as `ON` would needed to have been explicitly turned `ON` previously.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions, the application is running on a test server for now and I was creating the user. I don't know how, but if it's turned off by default then I had to turn it on somehow.